# how join 2 tables with different ids

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I got into a weird context in which

```
TableA
ID Field2 field3
1  Test1  IDB1
1  test1  IDB2
2  Test2  IDB3

TableB
ID Field2      field3
1  otherTest1  IDC1
1  othertest1  IDC2
2  otherTest2  IDC3
```

for each IDB we have a IDC. IDB and IDC are different but the number is the same, currently the only relationship is with ID. how could I join / paste those tables?
if I try a join obviously it will "duplicate" the rows cause IDB and IDC are different

a join will look like:

```
TableC
ID Field2 field3
1  IDB1  IDC1
1  IDB1  IDC2
2  IDB2  IDC3
```

what I want to accomplish is:

```
TableC
ID Field2 field3
1  IDB1  IDC1
1  IDB2  IDC2
2  IDB3  IDC3
3  IDB4  IDC4
3  IDB5  IDC5
4  IDB6  IDC6
```

Comment: You want to join on the last digit of the IDs? (This suggests you should better store the ID parts in two columns in each table, one for the alpha part and one for the numeric one.)

Comment: Does IDB/IDC text remain constant? you could replace IDB with empty string in your join, will be slow as anything. Suggestion above is better. separate those columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to remove your id column which is not common between the two tables to avoid the duplicates:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
a.fields, b.fields -- just don't use the id
FROM
tableA AS a
INNER JOIN
tableB AS b
ON
b.commonId = a.commonId
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm, you seem to want `union all` with some arithmetic on the id:

```
select a.id, a.field2, a.field3
from tableA a
union all
select a.max_id + b.id, b.field2, b.field3
from tableB cross join
     (select max(a2.id) as max_id from tableA a2) a
```

Answer (score 0):

one coworker suggested this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    a.id, a.IDB, b.IDC
FROM
    tableA AS a
INNER JOIN
    tableB AS b
ON
    a.id = b.id
```

the result is

```
ID Field2 field3
1  IDB1  IDC1
1  IDB2  IDC2
2  IDB3  IDC3
3  IDB4  IDC4
3  IDB5  IDC5
4  IDB6  IDC6
```